# .htaccess domain.com rewrite based on $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have never touched a .htaccess file. Can someone help me with the code I would need to replace a domain name with another domain name.

I have 10 domains pointed at the same directory as domain.com. When someone arrive via any of the 10 urls, I want them to see that URL through the entire visit on the site. So I need to do a rewrite that says to take domain.com and change it to $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. This variable holds the url a person typed to get to my site.

Please assist me, mod rewriting seems significantly more difficult then I would have imagined.

Comment: You can't rewrite the domain name. You need to do this through a combination of DNS entries and the virtual host settings. You can have multiple `ServerAlias` entries in the Apache configuration.

Comment: You are mixing mod_rewrite stuff (aliasing a path to a real resource, or redirecting an incoming request to another url), with managing the content of the ouput (the html and such). This is clearly a job for your application, it's your application job to return the right html content on your user session (and the session is also something managed by your app, not the http server)

Answer (score 1):

You can just write some code in your index file to redirect to new domain